# Streaming video from browser to Amazon Kinesis Video

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, streaming, webrtc, amazon-kinesis

I'm developing a web application that captures video from a webcam and saves the stream to Amazon Kinesis.
The first approach I came up with is getUserMedia / mediaRecorder / XMLHttpRequest which posts chunked MKV to my unix server (not AWS), where simple PHP backend proxies that traffic to Kinesis with putMedia.

This should work, but all media streams from user will go through my server which could become a bottleneck. As far as I know, it's not possible to post chunked mkv to Amazon directly from browser due to cross-origin problems. Correct me if I'm wrong or there's a solution for this.

Another thing that I feel I'm missing - is WebRTC. XHR feels a little bit like a legacy in 2019 for streaming media. But if I want this to work, I will need a stack of three servers: webrtc server to establish connection, webrtc->rtsp proxy, and Kinesis gstreamer plugin, which grabs rtsp stream and pushes it to Kinesis. It looks a bit overcomplicated, and media traffic still runs through my server. Or maybe there is a better approach?

I need a suggestion on how to make better architecture for my app. I feel the best solution would be direct webrtc connection with some amazon service, which proxies stream to kinesis. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into this also for general education/research purpose. The closest example is featured on AWS blog.
And this is [github repo](https://github.com/brain-power/Brain-Power-Amazon-Fidgetology/blob/master/README.md). From the README.md

> If the source is a sequence of buffered webcam frames, the browser client posts frame data to an API Gateway - Lambda Proxy endpoint, triggering the lambda/WebApi/frame-converter function. This function uses FFmpeg to construct a short MKV fragment out of the image frame sequence. For details on how this API request is executed, see the function-specific documentation.