# Can I create kinesis video producer from any android or web device without needing to install multiple libraries?

Tags: python, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I want to create a kinesis video stream from 10 different mobile and web device? How can I achieve this without installing different libraries in their devices?
Background: I want to use all their streams and pass them to open-cv for further post processing.

Comment: so you want to access devices without accessing devices?

Comment: By without accessing I mean, I only want their camera stream to be shared to kvs and not installing producer thing in their system, since they can be remote.

Comment: same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572169/how-can-i-stream-my-camera-frame-via-browser-using-amazon-kinesis-video-stream

Comment: I am here to get the answer, I don't really want to know if someone asked a similar question. It would be great if you could contribute by providing solution.

Comment: See this answer to pretty much the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563326/6718124.